# BackboneJS How to import module and insert in specific html element of main view

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Main view where I import external views(modules), fetch the collections and insert them as new Views inside specific HTML elements. But now I get an error I dont understand...

I have this view defined:

```
function (App, Backbone, auth) {

    var userNav = App.module();

    UserNav = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    )}
  return UserNav;
}
```

then in my Main view, I want to import the View `userNav`.

```
define(['app', 'backbone', 'modules/userNav'],

function (App, Backbone, UserNav,) {

    var Main = App.module();

    Main.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'main',
        ...
        afterRender: function(){
            var userNav = new UserNav.View();
            this.insertView('.usernav', userNav);       
        }
```

But I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` - and its referring to the line

```
var userNav = UserNav.View();
```

what is the issue here?

Comment: In your first code snippet you are switching case, instead of `var userNav= App.module()` you probably want `var UserNav = App.module()`.

Comment: @Jack Tried it, didnt solve the issue, I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is the UserNav.
try to define this as a module using this code.

```
define(['Backbone','App','auth'], function(Backbone,App, Auth){

    var UserNav = Backbone.View.extend({
     //Your code
    )}
  return UserNav;
});
```

This is the way that requireJs define a module.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`new UserNav()` instead of `new UserNav.View()`

UserNav is the View

Comment: you didn't tell us where insertView came from or if the dom contains a .userNav element so there's not much more help we can provide

Comment: insertView comes from Backbone `Layoutmanager`, sorry I didnt mention it and yes, the .userNav element is inside the `template:'main'`